# Replace brackets for negative numbers with hyphen

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm processing a list of numbers (as strings) in Ruby:

```
"4.3", "2.1", "(0.1)", "(3.4)"
```

When I process, I'd like to leave the positive numbers alone. For the negative numbers, I'd like to remove the brackets and insert a hyphen (keeping them as strings is fine):

```
"4.3", "2.1", "-0.1", "-3.4"
```

I've stripped the brackets with `gsub`:

```
"(0.1)".gsub(/[()]/, "")
```

But adding the hyphen to signify the negative causes problems, as this:

```
"(0.1)".gsub(/[()]/, "-\1")
```

... supposedly replaces both brackets, and puts two hyphens, along with an unknown character.

I'm not married to the gsub/regex approach, so anything that works quickly would work.

Comment: You mean parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: What do you mean by "[f]or the negative numbers"? You start with all positive numbers.

Comment: Parentheses, yes. I mean to say, the inputs will be a series of numbers, some positive, some negative, and whatever solution function would be run on all of them.

Comment: then, `"(0.1)".gsub(/\((\d+\.\d+)\)/, "-#$1")`

Comment: I tried that, and it just leaves me with a hyphen and nothing thereafter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
["4.3", "2.1", "(0.1)", "(3.4)"]
.map{|s| s =~ /\((.+)\)/ ? "-#$1" : s}
```

Comment: Good answer. `+1` I was just about to post.

Comment: Cool! Is there a non-array possibility, where you'd have just the string `(0.1)` to process on?